# MysqlDb and Pyqt4 comparing variables

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, mysql-python

I have a database in mysql, and I'm working in a app in QT4, I'm using Mysqldb connector, I'm already successfully connected to the database, but when I'm querying the table `t_usuarios` I don't know how to eval it. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Part of my code:

```
def chequeouser(self):
    passwdcheck = str(txt_password.text())
    usuariover =  str(txt_usuario.text())
   # datosLogin = "SELECT * FROM t_usuarios WHERE id_usuario = 'usuario' AND pasword = 'password'
    cursor = dbase.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT id_usuario, password FROM t_usuarios WHERE id_usuario = %s AND password = %s", (usuariover, passwdcheck))
    checar = cursor.fetchone()
```

Thanks for the user who answer me ... I do it, but with some modification as follow ..

```
 passwdcheck = str(txt_password.text())
    usuariocheck =  str(txt_usuario.text())
   # datosLogin = "SELECT * FROM t_usuarios WHERE id_usuario = 'usuario' AND pasword = 'password'
    cursor = dbase.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT id_usuario, password FROM t_usuarios WHERE id_usuario = %s AND password = %s", (usuariocheck, passwdcheck))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row  == None:
        print "no data:"+ usuariocheck
        return 
    if row[1] == passwdcheck:
        print "user and password combination is correct" +usuariocheck
    else :
        print "your input is incorrect"
```

I'm thinking do this in answer but I not sure if this is correct or not.

Comment: im used also ... this res = str(cursor.rowcount) but also return 0 ,

Comment: in PHP ... would use this.... [code]if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
    {
        $this->HandleError("Error logging in. ".
            "The username or password does not match");
        return false;
    }
    return true; [/code] but in python i dont know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchone()` returns a row of data.  The first item is row[0], 2nd item is row[1], etc.

Example:

```
def chequeouser(self):
    passwdcheck = str(txt_password.text())
    usuariover =  str(txt_usuario.text())
   # datosLogin = "SELECT * FROM t_usuarios WHERE id_usuario = 'usuario' AND pasword = 'password'
    cursor = dbase.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT id_usuario, password FROM t_usuarios WHERE id_usuario = %s AND password = %s", (usuariover, passwdcheck))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if not row:
       print "no rows!"
       return
    if passwdcheck == row[1]:
       print 'MATCH for user', row[0]
    else:
       print 'uhoh'
```

Comment: row = cursor.fetchone()
        if passwdcheck == row[1]:
            print 'MATCH for user', row[0]
        else:
            print 'uhoh'
...#### throws this error....        if passwdcheck == row[1]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: if i change "cursor.fetchone()" to cursor.fetchall() ·····>>     if passwdcheck == row[1]:
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: @mitsuzeroblackout probably the `SELECT` is not matching any rows, so the `fetchone()` returns None. I've updated the code.

Comment: just i made some changes, thanks @shavenwarthog ...row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row  == None:
            print "None in usuarios"+ usuariocheck
            return 
        if row[1] == passwdcheck:
            print "usuario existe : " +usuariocheck
        else :
            print "Error: need to check your inputs"